# SQS ReceiveMessage and SendMessage don't seem to work in batch with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

**Situation**

I use Lambda triggered by SQS with the following settings for my 100 queues:

- VisibilityTimeout: 330 seconds
- ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 20 seconds

and the settings for the event source mapping:

- BatchSize: 10000
- MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 300 seconds

In average a Lambda invocation is 2 seconds.

**Problem**

From what I undertand, `DeleteMessage`, `ReceiveMessage` and `SendMessage` should process up to 10 messages in a single request however my invoices clearly show `ReceiveMessage` and `SendMessage` don't do that.

As you can see on the plot below these 2 actions cost approximatively 10 times as much as `DeleteMessage`.

[image]

And yet the we don't observe this ratio for the number of messages:

| State | count | ratio | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| deleted | 7.039804e+09 | 0.264264 | 281.592162 |
| sent | 8.144990e+09 | 0.305752 | 3257.995994 |
| received | 1.145445e+10 | 0.429984 | 4581.779314 |

**Question**

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: *"my invoices clearly show ReceiveMessage and SendMessage don't do that"* - not at all what you see. If anything you see that there are more send and receive than there are deletemessagebatch requests, period. Also `SendMessage` cannot handle more than one message. Also having a large `MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds` does necessarily  affect how many receive calls are made against SQS. Check e.g. the `Number Of Empty Receives` on the monitoring of your queues to see if something looks off there. How many messages do you actually have in the queues? How often do messages arrive?

Comment: How many messages do your lambdas actually get invoked with? Having more `Receive` than `Send` suggest that you rarely have more than 1 message in a response which is only the case for low traffic queues. Looking at the ratio of ~1:10 for receive vs delete that could mean that your batching manages to collect 10 messages over the period of 300 seconds by submitting 10+ requests each getting 1 or 0 messages.

Comment: There are a few Empty Receives that may explain the difference between the sending and the reception as the traffic is constant and high.

What really bothers me is this ratio of 1:10 between the `DeleteMessage`  (or `SendMessage`) and `ReceiveMessage`. I can see, in the logs, that a lambda context is invoked with approx. 500 messages but I don't know how many lambda functions are used for this context. The concurrency is 100.

Comment: There is 0 available message and up to 3000 in-flight messages per queue.